# How to `pipenv uninstall` a package installed from an archive file on the web?

Tags: python, packaging, pipenv

I started to use pipenv a few days ago.  I have installed a 2.0.0 version of a library, I did:

```
pipenv intall https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=es_core_news_sm
```

Then I realized I need a 2.3.0 version, so I did

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.3.0/es_core_news_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz#egg=es_core_news_sm
```

And I would like to remove the previous one (2.0.0), so:

```
pipenv uninstall https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
Un-installing https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz…

No package https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz to remove from Pipfile.
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
```

So it looks like pipenv did not remove the first version.  The Pipfile still has lines for both:

```
[packages.f8ba4b6]                                                               
file = "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz"

[packages.0feb3d5]                                                               
file = "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.3.0/es_core_news_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz"
```

And so does the Pipfile.lock:

```
"default": {                                                                 
    "0feb3d5": {                                                             
        "file": "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.3.0/es_core_news_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz"
    }, 
    "f8ba4b6": {                                                             
        "file": "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz"
    }
}
```

I also tried uninstalling them like this:

```
pipenv uninstall  es_core_news_sm en_core_web_sm
Un-installing es_core_news_sm…
Found existing installation: es-core-news-sm 2.3.0
Uninstalling es-core-news-sm-2.3.0:
  Successfully uninstalled es-core-news-sm-2.3.0

No package es_core_news_sm to remove from Pipfile.
Un-installing en_core_web_sm…
Found existing installation: en-core-web-sm 2.2.0
Uninstalling en-core-web-sm-2.2.0:
  Successfully uninstalled en-core-web-sm-2.2.0
```

But the Pipenv still has the lines with the 2.0.0 version (the ones, I've pasted above).

Answer (score 0):

So far I have removed the obsolete 2.0.0 entry from Pipfile, then `pipenv lock`ed and now the Pipfile.lock does not have the 2.0.0 entry.  I however, wonder if the package is still in my .venv, poor lost soul.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in the virtual environment folder?

```
pipenv -venv
```

In my experience, the pipenv install/uninstall command only works for packages listed under [packages] and [dev-packages]. Somehow your install command generated another section - so it seems like you did the right thing just to remove it. If you install again using the same command as above:

```
pipenv install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=es_core_news_sm
```

You should end up with something like this:

```
[packages]
es-core-news-sm = {file = "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz"}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but unfortunately this is so obsolete for me ATM, that I won't try to see if your suggestion works.  I hope it might be helpful for the others though.